# Why is `extract_css` set to true for production by default?

Tags: production-environment, webpacker

I don't see any mention of the reason behind the defaults in either the [docs](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/css.md#link-styles-from-your-rails-views) or in the default generated `config/webpacker.yml`.

I saw someone mention (can't find the link now) that they have set `extract_css: false` in production without any problem and was interested in learning the pros and cons of both options for use in production.